# Is there a way to turn on global payload compression (gzip) on the ESB or API Manager?

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

Is there a way to switch on payload compression on either the ESB (< 5.0.0) or API Manager (< 2.0.0)  , specifically for application/json content-type ?

I have achieved this on a resource level but obviously a global option would be ideal.

After some research I have found the following available option in the catalina-server.xml :

compression="on" & compressableMimeType.

This does not help as the tomcat servers the web interface , not services , that is what axis2 is for.

After some more digging I found an archived article http://wso2.com/library/3316/. Inside it references the following :

"MC_GZIP_RESPONSE (Server, Writable) : By default the HTTP response body is not compressed. Set this message context property to true to have the response body be GZIP compressed."

Sounds like it is exactly what I need , but I am not sure about where to set this parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks "ycr". You set me on the right path.

What I did to achieve this was to create a global custom inSequence and outSequence (global extensions) for the api's deployed inside the API Manager , as mentioned in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions.

The inSequence checks for the value/existence of the Accept-Encoding header of the request and the outSequence gzips the response accordingly.

Steps:

Create the "inSequence" handler xml file:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
<property name="encoding" expression="$trp:Accept-Encoding"/>
<filter xpath="fn:contains(fn:lower-case(get-property('encoding')) , 'gzip')">
    <then>
        <property name="compression" value="true"/>
    </then>
    <else>
        <property name="compression" value="false"/>
    </else>
</filter>
```

The file name can be anything but the name inside the  tag needs to be WSO2AM--Ext--In

Similarly create the "outSequence" file :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--Out">
<filter source="get-property('compression')" regex="true">
    <then>
        <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="Content-Encoding" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="gzip"/>
        <property name="Transfer-Encoding" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="gzip"/>
    </then>
    <else>
        <property name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
    </else>
</filter>
```

Copy the files inside the /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences directory. They will be hot-deployed.

Send a request to any deployed api with the header Accept-Encoding set to gzip (any string with gzip in it will be compressed) and it should respond with Content-Encoding: gzip

Answer (score 1):

In Api Manager You can add this property to velocity_template.xml, So this will be added by default to all the APIs that's being created.